# Why can't I use array functions with an object variable pointing to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, binding

Lets say I have the following java code segment in front of me:

```
Integer[] iArr = {1,2,3};
Object o = iArr;
```

Why can't I do something like:

```
o[0]++;
```

What does the var o actually points to?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that you assign your array to `Object` and that class does not have an array accessor, nor can you do a post-increment on it. It doesn't matter what's actually "contained" in `o`.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually points to array of `Integer`, i.e. its type is `Integer[]`. You can check it if you do `o.getClass()`.

However java is strongly typed language. Compiler cannot know at compile time what will be actual type of `o`. So, if you want to use your variable as an array do not assign it to variable of type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but first you need to cast the type to array of proper type, to tell the compiler how you want to treat the variable:

```
((Integer[])o)[0]++;
```